# Refactoring to loop mySQL & PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I currently have an associative array called fields that stores all my  $_POST variables from my HTML input fields. The associative array variables are used when I try to bind my values to the mySQL database In the same manner, I also have the same names used as column headers for the mySQL database. So this is very tedious and long. Is there a way to perhaps loop through the columns and assign a value with another loop for the associative array? Please check the example below and thank you in advance for your help.

```
     try {
                $insertSql = "INSERT INTO tableExample";
                $sqlCols = " (
                    a,
                    b,
                    c,
                    d,
                    e,
                    f,
                    g,
                    h,
                    i,
                    j,
                    k,
                    l,
                    m,
                    n,
                    o,
                    p,
                    q,
                    r,
                    s,
                    t,
                    u,
                    v,
                    w,
                    x
                )";
                $result = $db->prepare($insertSql . $sqlCols . " VALUES (
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?)");
                $result->bindValue(1,$fields['a'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(2,$fields['b'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(3,$fields['c'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(4,$fields['d'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(5,$fields['e'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(6,$fields['f'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(7,$fields['g'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(8,$fields['h'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(9,$fields['i'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(10,$fields['j'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(11,$fields['k'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(12,$fields['l'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(13,$fields['m'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(14,$fields['n'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(15,$fields['o'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(16,$fields['p'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(17,$fields['q'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(18,$fields['r'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(19,$fields['s'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(20,$fields['t'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(21,$fields['u'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(22,$fields['v'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(23,$fields['w'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->bindValue(24,$fields['x'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $result->execute();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "Unable to store data";
                echo $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
```

Comment: You can always use a map binding field names and value indexes like $fields['a']=1; $fields['b']=2; or shorthanded like $fields=['a'=>1, 'b'=>2];. Then just iterate these fields and do your thing. Not the most elegant solution, but will suffice :). PD: Same names for post fields and database columns is unsafe, as it's basically exposing your database structure there!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickly cooked up a possible solution. Before trying it, please bear in mind that it's untested and there may be several syntax errors here (no PDO on my end... Actually, no php either).

What this does is define two separate maps: one for "database columns to indexes" and other for "database columns to values".

I can't be sure that this solves your problem but it's a starting point.

```
<?php
try 
{
    //Define your columns and indexes...
    $fields=['col_a' => 1, 'col_b' => 2, 'col_c' => 3, 'col_d' => 4];

    //Let this be your post data. Notice how the index are the same as above.
    $data=['col_a' => "Value a", "col_b" => 33, "col_c" => "Value C", "col_d" => 12];

    //Prepare the statement....
    $sqlCols=null;
    $sqlValues=null;

    foreach($fields as $key => $value) 
    {
        $sqlCols.=$key.',';
        $sqlValues.='?,';
    }

    $result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tableExample (".substr($sqlCols, 0, -1).") VALUES (".substr($sqlValues, 0, -1).")";

    //Bind the values... Please, make sure the order of parameters is correct!.
    foreach($fields as $key => $index)
    {
        $result->bindValue($index, $data[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    $result->execute();
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Unable to store data";
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Again, let me state that you're exposing your database structure through the names in your post variables. I doubt that's what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you @The Marlboro Man. This helped me a lot. I tried to up vote your answer but it said that it can't be publicly displayed.

Comment: @Roger, that's ok. Best of luck with the project!.